# Make dependencies (jar libraries) as native

Tags: maven, dependencies, graalvm

I'm woking on a legacy project (java+maven) which takes more the 40m to startup tomcat.

The overall problem is that there are to many submodules(300+) and over 620 dependencies (jar libraries).

I want to know:

Is possible to use graalvm make the libraries as natives?

Comment: First of all, one should understand where those 40m are spent. If it is issue of downloading dependencies from Maven via internet, then it would be reasonable to repackage your application as an uber-jar or similar assembly. On the other hand, if it is 40m of actual application startup time (meaning from entering main to ready state), then it is better to fix/redesign/refactor/rewrite application. In either case, graalvm should not be very helpful in your case.

Comment: @muradm
this 40m is only for startup the application, (no download dependencies). About  fix/redesign/refactor/rewrite there  are many team involved. First step is to try improve using some strategy in this  case Graalvm

Comment: 300+ submodule is a huge one... I would check which versions you are using if using the same version in all modules etc. how large is the resulting war file? Apart from that to use grallvm there are lot of requirements to get an app running in graalvm ...

Comment: @khmarbaise 338mb

Comment: @BrunoRozendo, then if your application is not under control of your team(s), it is bad. Right now you have problem of 40m startup time, which is very weird, and hardly believable be related to number of modules. Let's imagine that it is true and you decided to switch to graalvm (which is whole another story under this circumstances), suppose in order to do switch you will need to fix 128th module of those 300+. How you and your team(s) suppose to troubleshoot that problem and fix it under graalvm? The question you are asking is actually both incomplete and inadequate.

Comment: @BrunoRozendo i.e. if you and your team(s) can't fix 40m startup problem of your 300+ modules application, then they hardly will be able to switch that application to graalvm.

Comment: @muradm What I notice was most of time is spend on classpath. My question is: can I make the spring and all it depencies native? if is possible/doable then application should start faster. For example: on android when accessing the camera you call a method in java, but the implementation of this class is in C (https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Keywords/native). This is what I'm trying.

Comment: @BrunoRozendo, IMHO, Android example irrelevant, there you do write implementation your self, and plug it via native interface to Java.

Comment: @BrunoRozendo, IMHO, if you already know that issue is classpath, then hardly turning to native would be possible and/or beneficial in the context of Spring. Most thing behind the Spring is roughly call to Class.forName(...) for finding implementation and wiring etc. Which in reality translates to dynamic linking. JVM already very optimized for this kind of tasks. To benefit from static linking and binary translation for dramatic improvement you have to get rid of Class.forName(...) which is not realistic case for Spring.

Comment: Spring /Spring Boot can be made run on native (graalvm) but there are number of requirements to get that working. Also version important which version are you running of spring? And which version of JDK etc. apart from having that large size of  artifact? Only single artifact or a number of?